# Isit possible to union the similar GET requests in WEB output data in locust.io?

Tags: python, locust

Is it possible to union the similar GET requests in WEB output data in locust.io?
for example, I've such GET requests:

```
/get-user-settings/param1=value1&param2=value2
/get-user-settings/param1=value123&param4=value1234
```

So, locust, actually, show the results of the each request.
However, I need to gather the general statistic of the method /get-user-settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the the [documentation](http://docs.locust.io/en/latest/writing-a-locustfile.html#grouping-requests-to-urls-with-dynamic-parameters) you should be able to get all the requests in one place. In your case it would be something like:

```
client.get("/get-user-settings/param1=%i&param2=%j" % (i, j), name="Get User Settings")
```